# How to model animals of different types?

Tags: typescript

I have to query an animals API. The results are very similar to the following. Here is a `bird`.

```json
{
  "id": "...",
  "type": "bird",
  "details": {
    "color": "blue"
  }
}
```

Another result for a `dog`.

```json
{
  "id": "...",
  "type": "dog",
  "details": {
    "fur": "long"
  }
}
```

And another result for `dolphin`.

```json
{
  "id": "...",
  "type": "dolphin",
  "details": {
    "fins": 1
  }
}
```

I always get the `id` and the `type`. Depending on the `type`, those animals have different `details`. I'm currently doing the following in TypeScript.

```
interface BirdDetails {
  color: string
}

interface DogDetails {
  fur: string
}

interface DolphinDetails {
  fins: number
}

interface GeneralAnimal<Details> {
  id: string
  type: string
  details: Details
}

type Bird = GeneralAnimal<BirdDetails>
type Dog = GeneralAnimal<DogDetails>
type Dolphin = GeneralAnimal<DolphinDetails>

type Animal = Bird | Dog | Dolphin
```

Then I can query my API which returns an array of different animals of type `Animal[]`.

When I display an animal (e.g. in React) I loop through my `Animal[]` and then I use type guards to use the `details` in a type safe manner.

```
const isBird = (animal: Animal): animal is Bird => animal.type === 'bird'

// then it is safe to use animal.details.color
```

Is that the right approach? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: you could possibly take a look at discriminated unions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that we don't have proper discriminant in this type definition, therefore we need to write custom type guards, but even though we are not safe to create wrong data like that:

```
const a: Animal = {
    id: '1',
    type: 'bird',
    details: {
        fins: 1
    }
}
```

As you can see I can make a bird with wrong details.

In order to overcome the issue type needs to define discriminant, so the field which will be our unique identifier of our union element. In the example natural discriminant is `type` field. Check below code:

```
interface GeneralAnimal {
  id: string
  // if there is additional fields add them here
}

// here we define relation with type field and details structure
type Bird = GeneralAnimal & {type: 'bird', details: {color: string}}
type Dog = GeneralAnimal & {type: 'dog', details: {fur: string}}
type Dolphin = GeneralAnimal & {type: 'dolphin', details: {fins: string}}

type Animal = Bird | Dog | Dolphin

// I cannot create wrong Animal :) - compile error
const a: Animal = {
    id: '1',
    type: 'bird',
    details: {
        fins: 1
    }
}

// discriminant works without custom type guard
if (a.type === 'bird') {
    a // a is a Bird
}
```

Link to [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=2&pln=28&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELCgEwCITHYAGwGdkBvAWAChlkEB7Q%20qALmWLClAHNqBfatVCRYiFNnrdc%20IqUo1kMAK6t2nHv0FVh0eEmQTCABwAWoaQRLlqtGKGJsQSgLYAjaJqpDwuscgDiECDQcIQAgiDAzqEAPBayAHzWCsCYbBxcILwKYACeRhDp6lk2yJh4lg4GFbKe1AD09chwRlD0iCbIAO7AYJ3cQdDACKRaeQVoGJjIALwBg1ChEVGx6FjxJAnU4%20KSs-PBi%20GR0YRxkhvEW1Q7BoymoPuBh0snsYYPIJfX2-koy6d9mtpgAfO7cZBgj5mEBaRrIACSyAAVkoOHQoBA4JBpl02llkADQsh3EwusgANwACmoDBA6LgbCJhH28lotFSbAA5ABGLkAGlKtB23NcUwFQrKNRIbDZ7PldnpbB5koEVDVcKaLTaHW6vRM9CUYGQA0Ow2I1Hkku8Ij0KGeIWOKxZcs5aky2Vo8OAMGQfWgKGApDgmEwvWA9BAxLsEEImGDob9JggzmQycxdRuf0mWCeC1ezuQADJyCLkFyxVgBVKZDLyAwmKoMjw%20GrbhIIXMHUdmcXS39uZhJNXyrWqmRlE3itxW78JtDHl3807ASWyGWuUPjDCR9Lx4qqs2srOvFmJr25sDIeDrwvYaf4UiEHAQCB6MaEJjsSg8ZGIcyWFpSMGSZN4WTmOUOTScs%20UFBRhQHctK0wCV4JrSpZUlBV7GVVVM3hN8yiDT8olAF9jS6ZgAGs9T6Q0PzRMB6FTW5uCUOAsCEX0qTgAA6W4ZkEpDxQASmSeU4GQeFJKDZoc0wTN%20CAA). The whole concept has many names - tagged union, discriminated union, sum type. Here TS docs about that - [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type guards and it is the recommended way. I recently found a pdf book made by the typescript team which is simple and has lots of examples.

Page 45

https://www.typescriptlang.org/assets/typescript-handbook.pdf